# Reading XML stream.

Tags: c, stream

Could someone give me any hint how to do that?
With the code below I can read the data, but I have no idea if I break the node or not.

```
  for (;;) {
    bytes_received = recv ( socket_handle , input_buffer , 20000, 0 ) ;
    if ( bytes_received == -1 ) {
      printf ( "An error occured during the receive procedure \n" ) ;
      return 0 ;
    }
    if ( bytes_received == 0 ) break ;
    printf ( "%s" , input_buffer  ) ;
  }
```

Should I write it as file and use rather other language to process it?
Or can I save it in RAM and process from there?
Is it reasonable to do it with c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly plausible to read XML in a streaming fashion using C. What yo most likely want is a so-called `SAX` parser. Have a look at the [SAX interface](http://www.xmlsoft.org/interface.html) of [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).

SAX parsers work by incrementially feeding them bytes as you read them from e.g. a socket. Every time they detect that an element is started, a text was parsed etc. they invoke a callback function which lets you process the XML stream in an incremental fashion.

Comment: The documentation seems to be broken. I still read om my own, but wish to use a library. Could you give me any example of incremental feeding?